# Is it ok to ask questions about the balance of free content from DMsGuild?

Tags: discussion, questions, dnd-5e

I've found several subclasses, optional rules, and other content on [Dungeon Master's Guild](https://dmsguild.com) that I'd like to use in a game, all of which are Free or Pay What You Want. Is it OK to ask questions about the balance of this type of content? If so, would this use the [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review) tag, or something else?

Comment: I think I’ve got a meta answer *somewhere* around here where I discuss handling questions like this the same way we do homebrew reviews.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, we handle these sorts of questions

It doesn’t actually really matter if it’s homebrew on some forum somewhere, something posted to the DM’s Guild for free or at some cost, or even official material: “what effects would adding this content to my game have?” is a reasonable question and one which we have handled just fine numerous times in the past.

As for [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review)... yes, I think it should apply, but then, it should probably also apply to a question of “hey, this new official book came out, and I have doubts about this new class,” which is fundamentally the same sort of question, but calling that “homebrew” review is just wrong. I think we should, perhaps, rename the tag [content-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-review), or something?

Comment: Is it permissible to directly copy & paste the content?

Comment: @User23415 generally no; it's not okay to copy and paste content wholesale because copyright. You can link it, summarize your concerns, or paste relevant snippets, or ideally all three.

Comment: @KRyan Not a bad idea on the tag rename!

Comment: I dislike the tag rename, because if a new person searches the tags for "homebrew", the tag should really show up. I'm no SE specialist, but can we have multiple tag names pointing to the same tag or something?

Comment: @Gloweye A tag can be *synonymised* with another. That acts as an alias - all existing questions with the synonym will use the canonical tag and people searching for the synonym will find the canonical as well. For example [dnd-5th-edition] is [a synonym of \[dnd-5e\]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/dnd-5e/synonyms) and if you try to use the synonym in the tags [you will find the \[dnd-5e\]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiuz9.png).

Comment: Then this sounds like a very appropriate place for a synonym, rather than a full rename.

Comment: @Gloweye Yes, the two should definitely be synonyms—pretty sure that’s inherent in a tenant, that the old becomes synonym for the new, but thinking again maybe not. Anyway that was my intent. But anyway, with synonyms, we don’t keep both tags. All uses of the synonym become the canonical tag automatically. Here, I think homebrew-review sound be the synonym, not canonical.